# Issues with C pthreads and a malloc/seg fault error

Tags: c, multithreading

having some problems with my C code (kinda new to this language). I have the following code:
..

```
RTSPClient *clientInfo = (RTSPClient*) malloc(sizeof(RTSPClient));
if (!clientInfo)
{
printf("There wasn't enough memory to fufill the connection.\n");
continue;
}
clientInfo->socket = new_fd;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handleClientConnection, (void *) clientInfo);
```

...

where RTSPClient is the following

```
typedef struct {
    int socket;
    int session_id;
    PlaybackTimer* playback_timer;
    CvCapture* video;
} RTSPClient;
```

When we try to access the video field in the struct, we are getting seg faults. Were clearly not allocating things correctly, but wondering how we can fix this issue. Do I need to keep a global variable to the clientInfo object allocated before the thread was started, or do I need to allocate it statically?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you set video and playback_timer to point to? as it stands they point to some random location in memory

Comment: Please remove all casts where you don't know **exactly** what you are doing and can explain why the cast is **neccessary** for correct working. Never muzzle the compiler, instead ask it to speak up: Use `-Wall -Wextra`, and handle all warnings appropriately.

Comment: `void openVideo(CvCapture* video, char* file_path)
{
 // Open the video file.
 video = cvCaptureFromFile(file_path);

 if (!video) {
  printf("could not open video %s\n", file_path);
 }
}`

Comment: sorry not sure how to format!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RTSPClient *clientInfo = (RTSPClient*) malloc(sizeof(RTSPClient));` creates the memory only for the `clientInfo` structure. You also need to allocate memory for `CvCapture* video;` and all the other pointers. (if you do, please show more code how you work with the allocated structure).

And are you sure you meant `continue` in case the memory allocation failed? I think you should abort your application if there is not enough memory... or nothing will work.

(And you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C application)

Comment: Right I was thinking that, however I don't really know why I cannot malloc something of size CvCapture, for example `clientInfo->video = (CvCapture*) malloc(sizeof(struct CvCapture));` just gives me the error `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct CvCapture’`

Comment: This is different. You do not have the full struct declaration of `CvCapture`. The structure `CvCapture` does not have public interface and is used only as a parameter for video capturing functions. (opencv doc)

Comment: Use either `cvCreateFileCapture` or `cvCreateCameraCapture` to obtain a `CvCapture` struct

Comment: a `CvCapture` gets allocated through `cvCreateCameraCapture()`.